# Normalised Integral image

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I have computed the integral image of a given image by using `ii = cumsum(cumsum(image, 2), 1)`; In my coursework, the question asked me to plot the normalised Integral Image which really confused me because most values will be larger than 255 and I will get a bright image. So how to plot the normalised Integral Image?

Comment: Can you show what you have tried?

Comment: So did my answer help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just simply normalize the image.  It looks like you're using MATLAB, so just create a new image that normalizes the values between 0 - 255:

```
ii_norm = 255*(ii - min(ii(:))) / (max(ii(:)) - min(ii(:)));
```

The operation first assumes that you are normalizing within the range of `[0,1]`, then you scale to `[0,255]` after.  Since you want to display this as an image, don't forget to cast this as `uint8`:

```
ii_norm = uint8(ii_norm);
```

However, you can use [`imagesc`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/imagesc.html) to automatically scale the values so that they conform to the above range anyway.  However, `imagesc` will show the image using a colour map that colours intensities with a unique colour.  I suspect you may want to show the actual intensity values themselves, so you will have to call [`colormap`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/colormap.html) and set it to `gray` to do this.  Additionally, you can use [`imshow`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/images/imshow.html) with the second parameter as being empty to help you do this scaling: `imshow(ii, []);`... in fact, you don't even need to scale it at all. You would if you wanted to write the image to file.

Just simply do:

```
imagesc(ii); colormap('gray');
% or
%imshow(ii,[]);
```

... and the above will automatically scale the image to the range of `[0,255]` or `[0,1]` in the case of floating-point.

What you should expect is an image with an increasing gradient where the top-left is 0 or close to zero and as you approach the bottom-right, the image starts to increase in intensity to the point where it becomes completely white as you approach close to the bottom-right corner of the image.  Remember that an integral image computes the area from the top-left of the image to a spatial coordinate `(x,y)`.

Also, depending on the size of your image the integral image values may fill up very quickly, so it may be useful to display the **log** normalized intensity image as well:

```
imagesc(log(1 + ii)); colormap('gray');
% or
imshow(log(1 + ii), []);
```

This will give you a more even distribution of intensities as you sweep from the top-left to the bottom-right.